# SignalR hosted in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, signalr

I just spent a lot of time created a web service, which will be used by 2 winforms applications.  My intention was to use SignalR, having the hub in the web service, and each winforms app would be a client.  So when a client made a given web service call, I could then publish certain information to every other client as part of the web service call.  However, I'm getting the impression that I cannot use a web service (as opposed to a website) as a host for SignalR, as there is no place to put

```
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
using (WebApp.Start<startup>(url))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

which would normally go in "sub main" (of a console app) or "application_start" (of a website).  Is there a way to do this, or am I going to have to create a separate project to actually host SignalR and then call that from the web service?

Comment: When you say you created a web service, you mean a WCF app right? Web service is a pretty ambiguous term. If so, why are you bothering with a WCF app at all? The clients can invoke server methods via SignalR, it's bidirectional.

Comment: I meant a WCF service, yes.  So you're saying why not just have a console app that basically provides the same functionality as a wcf service?  Meaning I would call a server method from the client just as I would have called the wcf service, but I don't need a wcf service since the clients can call methods on the SignalR hub directly.  Is that what you're suggesting?  That seems logical to me, I just hadn't thought about it in that way, so I had it in my head that I'd be calling the wcf service from the clients.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Why have two different service architectures? SignalR can't do everything WCF can do, but if it does what you need it to do, you might as well simplify the entire thing by cutting out WCF.

Comment: I think that's what I'll do then.  I can't think of a reason why I need it to be a WCF service, so it should work okay for me.  Thanks.